# Is it illegitimate to name an JPA entity "Group"?

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, java-ee-6, jpa-2.0

I'm developing a JEE6-application, using JPA 2.0 and Hibernate 3.5.2-Final as the Provider (and MySQL 5.1.41). My Application Server is Glassfish V3.0.1.
I already have a working CRUD-app with some entities and relationships.

Now i added an (really simple) entity with the name "Group". The entity class looks like this:

```
package model
//Imports...
@Entity
public class Group {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  private String name;

  //Getters and Setters
}
```

Of course I also added it to the persistence.xml, like `<class>model.Group</class>`. My persistence.xml drops and recreates all tables on deploy.

So when i deploy my application, the tables for all my entities are generated, except for the table group. In the hibernate logs, i discovered the following error (which doesn't prevent the application to be deployed)

```
[#|2010-06-30T11:54:29.862+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Binding entity from annotated class: model.Group|#]
[#|2010-06-30T11:54:29.862+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Bind entity model.Group on table Group|#]
[#|2010-06-30T11:54:33.773+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Unsuccessful: create table Group (id bigint not null auto_increment, name varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))|#]
[#|2010-06-30T11:54:33.773+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group (id bigint not null auto_increment, name varchar(255) not null, primary ke' at line 1|#]
[#|2010-06-30T11:54:54.883+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Binding entity from annotated class: model.Group|#]
[#|2010-06-30T11:54:54.884+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Bind entity model.Group on table Group|#]
[#|2010-06-30T11:54:58.402+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Unsuccessful: create table Group (id bigint not null auto_increment, name varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))|#]
[#|2010-06-30T11:54:58.403+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.0.1|org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group (id bigint not null auto_increment, name varchar(255) not null, primary ke' at line 1|#]
```

Now when i rename the entity to something like "MyGroup" (the properties stay the same), alter the persistence.xml accordingly, and redeploy my app, the table "MyGroup" is successfully created! I found the following lines in the logs showing that MyGroup is correctly created:

```
[#|2010-06-30T11:58:51.456+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Binding entity from annotated class: model.MyGroup|#]
[#|2010-06-30T11:58:51.456+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder|_ThreadID=11;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Bind entity model.MyGroup on table MyGroup|#]
[#|2010-06-30T11:59:21.569+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Binding entity from annotated class: model.MyGroup|#]
[#|2010-06-30T11:59:21.569+0200|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Bind entity model.MyGroup on table MyGroup|#]
```

Anyone got an idea what the problem is? 
Okay, i could just rename Group to MyGroup, but i really want to know what's going on here. Is there any restriction i should now of, like "don't call an entity Group"? But if it is so, why is the error i get so unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group is a reserved word in your database MySQL see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)

```
package model
//Imports...
@Entity
@Table(name = "group_table")
public class Group {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  private String name;

  //Getters and Setters
}
```

*edit*
See @Pascals answer for JPA 2.0 way if you want to use words reserved in your db instance.

Answer (score 17):

You can use reserved keywords for database objects names if you tell the JPA provider to escape them. This has been standardized in JPA 2.0 as described in the following section of the specification:

> ### 2.13 Naming of Database Objects
>
> (...)
>
> To specify delimited identifiers, one
> of the following approaches must be
> used:
>
> - It is possible to specify that all database identifiers in use for a
>   persistence unit be treated as
>   delimited identifiers by specifying
>   the `<delimited-identifiers/>` element
>   within the `persistence-unit-defaults`
>   element of the object/relational xml
>   mapping file. If the
>   `<delimited-identifiers/>` element is
>   specified, it cannot be overridden.
> - It is possible to specify on a per-name basis that a name for a
>   database object is to be interpreted
>   as a delimited identifier as follows:
> - Using annotations, a name is specified as a delimited identifier by
>   enclosing the name within double
>   quotes, whereby the inner quotes are
>   escaped, e.g.,
>   `@Table(name="\"customer\"")`.
> - When
>   using XML, a name is specified as a
>   delimited identifier by use of double
>   quotes, e.g., `<table name="&quot;customer&quot;"/>`

So the JPA 2.0 way would be to specify the `Table` like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Group\"")
public class Group {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  private String name;

  //Getters and Setters
}
```

This is definitely supported by Hibernate (see <strike>[HHH-4553](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4553)</strike>), no leaky abstraction here.

Answer (score 3):

You can quote the 'group' keyword by using the following @Table annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`group`")
public class Group {
...
}
```

I know this is an answer to an old question, but I thought it may help someone.

Answer (score 2):

With some JPA implementations you can use classes with names like that, and the JPA implementation does the sensible thing and "quotes" the name in any SQL (since it is a reserved word as pointed out by Paul Whelan), so it is accepted. [DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform) certainly allows this no problem.

Comment: Interesting. So isn't it a bug in Hibernate? In my opinion it really should be either quoted, or at least there should be a clear exception from Hibernate.

Comment: I'm not in a position to say if something in a competing piece of software is a bug (it's beyond the JPA spec fwiw), but prefer to leave it to users of that software to decide if they find it acceptable such behaviour when there are alternatives around that don't have such a limitation, and where there is a clear way of providing support for it