# Spring JPA - "in" word in package name of Entity Class - Results in JPQL Error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

*Issue observed with Spring-Data with Hibernate - Spring 4.1.5.RELEASE, Spring-Data - 1.8.0.RELEASE, Hibernate - 4.3.8.Final*

Domain name of company ends with .in as it is in India.
Hence, my Java packages starts with "in.something....".

When using JPA Repository, if I have to use custom query on a method like below:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT o FROM UserEntity o, UserAttribute u where o.organization.organizationType.code in ?1 and o.status in ?2 and u.attrKey = 'SOL_ID' and u.attrValue in ?3 and u.userEntity = o") 

Page<UserEntity> findByOrganizationAndStatusAndSolId(List<String> organizationTypes, List<StatusMaster> statusList, List<String> solId, Pageable pageable);
```

The application startup is failing because the JPA Query has fully qualified name for classes, and since package starts with "in", it thinks that there is a validation error.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting OPEN,
>   found '.' near line 1, column 44 [SELECT o FROM
>   in.something.UserEntity o, in.something.UserAttribute u where
>   o.organization.organizationType.code in ?1 and o.status in ?2 and
>   u.attrKey = 'SOL_ID' and u.attrValue in ?3 and u.userEntity = o]

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page in.something.UserRepository.findByOrganizationAndStatusAndSolId(java.util.List,java.util.List,java.util.List,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.fromQueryAnnotation(SimpleJpaQuery.java:169)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:158)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:44)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting OPEN, found '.' near line 1, column 44 [SELECT o FROM in.something.UserEntity o, in.something.UserAttribute u where o.organization.organizationType.code in ?1 and o.status in ?2 and u.attrKey = 'SOL_ID' and u.attrValue in ?3 and u.userEntity = o]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1364)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294)
```

I tried variety of options, but with no luck:

1. Using  [Suggestions from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148249/is-it-illegitimate-to-name-an-jpa-entity-group/3149445#3149445) to use escape table name in Entity
2. Use `<delimited-identifiers/>`
3. Specify a name in @Entity(name="otherName")

Any inputs on this will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Code used to work fine when my package was starting with "com.something".
However, I re-factored code to fix package names, after that, issues started showing up

**UPDATE 2**
If the query is modified to use `SELECT o FROM UserEntity o JOIN o.attributes u...` then the error goes away.

**UPDATE 3 - Issue found in UPDATE too**

```
@Query(value="UPDATE WebSessionEntity o SET o.lastAccessedOn = ?2 WHERE o.authSessionToken = ?1")
public int updateLastAccessedOn(String authSessionToken, Date accessDate);
```

Assuming WebSessionEntity starts with package name "in.something...", then the application does not start.  During start-up, I get Hibernate validation error:

```
2015-03-24 18:52:00,810 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter - line 1:8: unexpected token: in line 1:8: unexpected token: in    
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.updateStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:210)
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!     
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:63)  
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272)
```

Comment: I don't see how "in.xxx" is invalid JPQL. "IN" is a JPQL keyword and would be invalid, but there are no spaces after it in your case, hence it is not a keyword as such. I suggest that the problem is a bug in your JPA implementation. Try a different implementation to see how it interprets such a query?

Comment: Actually I just tried a simple "SELECT p FROM in.model.Person p" with DataNucleus JPA and it works fine; the "in." is not considered a JPQL "keyword".

Comment: @NeilStockton  Yeah that type of simple queries work fine.  When I have two entities separated by comma to indicate JOIN (FROM UserEntity o, UserAttribute u where), I saw that error.

Comment: If I use SELECT o FROM UserEntity o JOIN o.attributes u  then I don't see that error anymore.

Comment: I can do comma-separated queries like "SELECT p FROM in.model.Person p, in.model.Project pr" fine also (with DataNucleus JPA).

Comment: We are using Spring-JPA with Hibernate as JPA impl.  Upgraded to latest Spring & Hibernate, still same issue (as mentioned in UPDATE -3  above)

Comment: so raise an issue in the issue tracker of your JPA implementation with the query it is trying to run and the exception. That doesn't give you a workaround though (other than it works in other JPA impls)

Comment: There is a JIRA issue. Have a look at this https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-659. I understood back it then that this was because the package name started with an SQL key word.

Comment: @WandMaker did you find any solution?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

By convention, when a domain name is interfering with naming a package, an underscore is used.

Link - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

An excerpt from the link,

> In some cases, the internet domain name may not be a valid package
>   name. This can occur if the domain name contains a hyphen or other
>   special character, if the package name begins with a digit or other
>   character that is illegal to use as the beginning of a Java name, or
>   if the package name contains a reserved Java keyword, such as "int".
>   In this event, the suggested convention is to add an underscore.

Comment: The issue is happening because "in" is SQL keyword.  Not because its a invalid domain name

Comment: I understand that but since it is present in the package name it makes the package name invalid.

Comment: The package name is not invalid, and nor is the query. "in" is a JPQL keyword *if it has whitespace around it* ... and it doesn't.