# Spring Data JPA JPQL reserved word exception due to package name

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Using JPQL, because the following query references more than 1 entity, the rendered SQL contains the package names of MyTableA and MyTableB. In my case, my Java package names start with "is" because I live in Iceland (Island). I get an exception: "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker: line 3:6: unexpected token: is". Seems as though Hibernate's HQLParser/HQLLexer is errantly failing with a reserved-word exception. Does anyone have any experience with anything like this? This forces me to use native queries instead of JPQL, and stops me from using tools like QueryDsl. Thank you for any advice.

````
    """
     SELECT a FROM MyTableA a JOIN MyTableB b on a.id = b.id WHERE a.id = :id
     """, MyTest.class)
.setParameter(“id”, id)
.getResultList(); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think you you don't need to specify fully-qualified name of entity classes in JQPL queries. Try to use simple class names instead of fully qualified names.

See the similar issue with `in` keyword in package name: [Spring JPA - "in" word in package name of Entity Class - Results in JPQL Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230286/spring-jpa-in-word-in-package-name-of-entity-class-results-in-jpql-error)

Comment: The "full-qualified name of entity" is something Spring is doing somewhere under the hood. If I use I single entity, a query will work. If I add a join, Spring seems to modify the sql to include the full-qualified bit, probably for mapping purposes. I didn't know about the _ thing. I'll try that. That said, I feel that if Spring auto-adds the package name, it really should sprinkle _ where needed.